# Linux copy file on the basis of input date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date, variables

I have some files in a directory with name pattern raw_YYYY-MM-DD.csv (e.g. raw_2014-04-01,raw_2014-04-02,....) i want to write a script to copy these files on the basis of input date which should be prompted to user and then file name should be taken as input.

I tried to write below but its not asking to input date while running in script:

```
date=
while [ -z $date ]
do
    echo -n 'Date? '
    read date
done
cd "/path";
cat rawfile_$date-* > /path2/file.txt;
```

Please check and suggest what i am missing.

Comment: i didn't understood the concept of file name taken as input after prompting the date.. pls explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always quote your variables unless you're sure you want it to undergo word splitting and wildcard expansion.

```
while [ -z "$date" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

PATH is an environment varible , so set it before running the script

```
while [ -z "$date" ]
do
    echo -n 'Date? '
    read date
done
cd $PATH
#check if file is present
if [ -f raw_"${date}"-* ]
then
   echo "file not present"
   exit 1
fi
cat raw_"${date}"-* > /path2/file.txt
```